# Slow response from MVC controller

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I have a weird problem.

From a controller I do receive very slow response. What is going on. 
I do have a Dynamic Web service call from this controller to our backend software. The response from the backend is processed in about 30-500ms. 
The serialization process is about 0ms-10ms.

When the controller is returning the data to the client (browser) with 24K woth of JsonData it takes the server about 2.8s ans 250ms to render to respond, If the server is returning ie 300K of json data it takes only 500ms to respond and 1s to render.. My method.

What I tried so far change the Serialization From Json to JsonNet to plan string response but all the same..

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string RetriveMultiple(RequestParams model)
    {
        Stopwatch st = new Stopwatch();
        st.Start();

        var def = UI.GetDefinitionFor(model.ModuleName);

        var service = DynamicServiceProxy.DynamicServiceHelper.CreateWebService(model.RequestedEntity);

        ArrayList filters = new ArrayList();

        if (null != model.RequestFilters)
            foreach (var f in model.RequestFilters)
            {
                filters.Add(service.CreateFilter(f.Field, f.Criteria));
            }

        dynamic response = new string[0];
        try
        {
            response = service.ReadMultiple(filters, model.PageKey, model.PageSize != null ? (int)model.PageSize : 30);
        }
        catch
        {
            service = DynamicServiceProxy.DynamicServiceHelper.CreateWebService(model.RequestedEntity, true);
            response = service.ReadMultiple(filters, model.PageKey, model.PageSize != null ? (int)model.PageSize : 30);
        }

        st.Stop();
        LogHelper.Info<EntityServiceSurfaceController>(() => {
            return string.Concat("Search time ",  st.Elapsed.Milliseconds, "ms, row count ", response.Length );
        });

        st.Reset();
        st.Start();
        var r = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);
        st.Stop();
        LogHelper.Info<EntityServiceSurfaceController>(() => {
            return string.Concat("Serialisation time ", st.Elapsed.Milliseconds, "ms, row count ", response.Length);
        });


        return r;
        //return new JsonNetResult
        //{
        //    Data = r
        //};
    }
}
```

Stopwatch times.

```
 2015-12-03 17:48:15,254  - Search time 295ms, row count 17
 2015-12-03 17:48:15,254 - Serialisation time 0ms, row count 17
```

[image: Chrome timeline]

[image: Newtork times (Fiddler)]

Comment: drop the dynamic from `dynamic response = new string[0];`

Comment: Dos not help. serialization of the dynamic object is about 0-10ms..

Comment: Put the stopwatch at different places until you can confirm which bit is actually taking the most time and then edit your post.

Comment: I did updated may question.

Comment: Don't forget you need to download that 24K once the controller has responded. The speed depends on your connection speed, etc.

Comment: Green represents waiting for the server blue downlowding..

Comment: ...ish, green represents how long the **client** waits for the response. This may not represent the servers view of things.

Comment: Why don't you just profile the app? Put on high load, then pause the debugger 10 times. It will stop most often where most time is spent.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a ASP.NET filter? These run before and after action methods and implement features like security and logging.

Check the globally-registered filters, usually in `App_Start\FilterConfig.cs`.

```
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new DisallowJsonCachingAttribute());
        filters.Add(new ApplyJsonCacheControlAttribute());
```

Also, check if the controller has any suspicious filters applied.

I'm assuming this is slow for just this method? Are there others that work well?

Comment: why 2 answers? you should really add this to your original answer.

Comment: Just for this one, everything else is very fast. There is a bit of an conundrum If I do load a bigger data set it renders faster..

Comment: @Liam these are two distinct approaches, One could be right, one could be wrong. Two different threads of discussion. Hence, two answers.

Comment: This seems like it is suited for a comment and not an answer.

Comment: I too like poorly formatted and hard to read comments that are actually meant to answer the posted question.